# Looking for a large data set of French data

Tags: data-request, big-data, france

As I am a French student in IT I have to work on a Big-Data project using French data (the country, not the language). 
What I'm looking for is a data set of something  interesting like weather or traffic which is large (more than 100 Gb) and frequently updated.

I do not really know where to look at and I will appreciate and considere any suggestion.

Comment: more than 100GB will be hard to reach. To reach this volume I will look to log file

Answer (score 5):

I also think that [Twitter data](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/streaming) is the best way to get >100Gb french dataset.

OpenStreetMaps gives really great open data but you can't reach 100Gb easily : [the Integral Metropolitan France dataset](https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/dataset/donnees-openstreetmap-integrales-de-france-metropolitaine) is 2.6 GB.

There is no open weather data by [MeteoFrance](https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr) (you have to pay the licence) but there is an [Open Meteo Forecast that you can try](http://data.openmeteoforecast.org). I never had the opportunity to use it but I guess it can provide you large amount of data.

You also have [the dataset "Tous les documents" from the BNF](http://data.bnf.fr/semanticweb) that is 1.5GB and looks quite interesting.

Hope it can help.
Cheers

Comment: Too bad MeteoFrance does not have an Open Data project. There is still a lot to do in France ...
Twitter data are great but there is a lot of work to identify trustable tweets and interesting ones

I'll take a look to the BNF one, thanks !

Comment: Yes, clearly, but maybe it's going to move forward after the [Trojette Rapport this year](http://www.lemonde.fr/politique/article/2013/11/05/un-rapport-prone-la-gratuite-des-donnees-des-etablissements-publics_3508352_823448.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can check the databases of the [INSEE](http://www.insee.fr/en/bases-de-donnees/) (National Institute of Statistics and Economic Studies).

If you are a teacher or student you can use the online statistical data for non-commercial use [details over here](http://www.insee.fr/en/publics/default.asp)

Answer (score 2):

There was a [similar (French) question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1801/1511) recently and I posted several answers. The difference may be that you are interested in France-data and the other question was for French-language data. I think the most appropriate answer was for collecting Twitter data, which I'll describe here with some additions to make it specific for France.

- [Twitter data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1802/1511) can easily grow to more than 100 GB, if you let the public live stream run or you search constantly. Once you have your own decent-sized private corpus, you can do all the testing/training while the data collects in the background. You can select French-language tweets by including '[lang:fr](https://twitter.com/search?q=lang:fr&src=typd)' in the search/stream paramters. To include only tweets from France, you can [filter by geolocation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations). Note that only a sub-set of tweets have geolocation activated. Also, note that the language is sometimes incorrectly identified, especially for short, cryptic tweets.

---

For other France-specific data, consider downloading from the [OpenStreetMaps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=13/43.2122/5.5012) project. Perhaps someone who is more familiar with that project can expand on what data is avaiable that meets your needs.

Comment: I read the other question (and answers) before asking and considered twitter data. 
But the goal of my work is to work with some data provided by a French company, like data.gouv.fr .. As you said I'm looking for 'French Data'
The government published interesting datasets but they are too small for this project

Answer (score 2):

The US National Intelligence Agency (NGA) maintains a geographic feature database for each country in the world. The data is kept in the Geographic Name Server (GNS). The format is somewhat arcane by today's standards. I have converted each country's dataset into a standardized CSV format to make it more friendly to developers.

The France dataset contains ~98,000 records.

http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.1/NGA/GNS/FR.zip

Metadata on the vocabulary used for the fields in the dataset is defined here:

http://www.opengeocode.org/cude1.1/LinkedCSV-Vocab.php

Answer (score 2):

Website of the government open data project.

http://www.data.gouv.fr/

Everything you want and more.

Comment: Yes there is lots of data, but we can't consider any of those sets as a 'Big Data' set, can we ?
If you find some large one can you link it here please ? :)

Comment: @lmorin - can you expand on some specific data sets that would be interesting?