# User reviews for consumer tech products, but in French

Tags: data-request, nlp, french

So I am working on a sentiment analysis project where I need to gather french reviews about some giving product (iPhone XR, PS5, or anything as long as there is enough data), I tried Reddit (praw API) but most of the comments are in English, twitter(Tweeppy API) couldn't get more than 5k reviews because of the API limitations (couldn't get tweets older than 1 week). My question is: if anyone ever worked on a similar project, please could you tell me what API and website you used or if there any other alternatives.

Please feel free to ask me anything if the subject is not clear to you.

Comment: Anything here? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/1801/1511